# Vista laptop keeps waking up a minute after I put it to sleep

Tags: windows-vista, sleep, power-management, device-manager, powercfg

I have used the command

```
powercfg -lastwake
```

to determine what is waking up my computer. Here is what it produces in prompt

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 1
  Wake Source [0]
    Type: Fixed Feature
    Timer Expired (RTC)
```

Next to Type: it says *Fixed Feature*. I assume that means something internal.  Also when I run the command

```
powercfg devicequery wake_armed
```

nothing is printed out in prompt which further reinforces that idea that something inside the laptop is waking the laptop. I have a battery that holds a charge for no longer than a 30 seconds to a minute but I am leaving the laptop plugged in after putting it to sleep.

I have also looked into my Device Manager and made sure that *"Allow this device to wake the computer"* was unchecked on every device that has a **Power Management** tab.

Another thing I did was go into **Power Options** > **Advanced settings** > **Multimedia settings** > **When sharing media** > **Plugged in:** and changed that option to *"Allow the computer to sleep"*

Comment: the RTC flag seems to suggest some Scheduled task item. Is it always one minute exact?  Does the event viewer show anything for that time? Got any trialware that ended?  I assume if it is 1 minute everytime, that it never goes back to sleep?

Comment: Here is a similar , http://www.vistax64.com/general-discussion/187088-vista-spontaneously-awakens-standby-3.html see the second to the last post. Looks like it BREAKS it altogether. Myself I would not do that , unless I had at least a registry backup first. or the steps to undo it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently all I had to do was enter the BIOS and disable the ability to wake the computer from incoming network data. Now everything is fine.